# How much of the new Battlestar Galactica do I need to have seen to play Battlestar Galactica Online?

Tags: suggested-order, battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-online

I have seen the miniseries and first season of the reimagined BSG series. Is this enough to play BSG Online without spoilers? If not, what do I need to have seen? (Note: I don't want any major or minor spoilers that are obvious. Non-obvious references and the like are okay.)

Comment: Simply by reading the site, half-way through season 2, though it appears the game has taken liberties with the plot

Answer (score 3):

Based on the plotline [outlined on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Battlestar_Galactica_video_games#Battlestar_Galactica_Online), the show and the online game diverge at BSG Season 2, Episode 12; [Resurrection Ship Part II](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Resurrection_Ship,_Part_II).

The game's blurb offers a significant number of spoilers for the first two seasons;

> *Man created the Cylons. The Cylons evolved. The Cylons Rebelled. The
> game begins 40 years after the first Cylon war. The Cylons paid a
> visit to the Twelve Colonies to annihilate the humans and take their
> resources. The aging Battlestar Galactica managed to escape the
> attack, gather a fleet of civilian ships, and set out for the home of
> the legendary 13th Colony (Earth). The Cylons pursued Battlestar
> Galactica for months until Battlestar Galactica reunited with Pegasus,
> the other survivor from the Cylon attack. Together, they were strong
> enough to retaliate and destroy the Cylon’s Resurrection Ship.*

And then below this line, the plotline diverges from the TV series;

> *When the Cylons discovered that the humans destroyed the Resurrection
> Ship, they launched a colossal counter strike against the Colonial
> Fleet. The unsuspecting Colonials were forced to jump away to safety,
> but they suffered a mechanical malfunction in the process. A massive
> pulse of energy overloaded the FTL drives on both fleets, which
> triggered an uncontrolled jump that threw them off target.*
>
> *In Battlestar Galactica Online, the Cylons and Colonials are stranded
> at the edge of one of the galactic arms. Both Colonial fleets are
> heavily damaged and low on critical resources. The race begins for the
> Colonials to repair and rearm their ships, escape and continue their
> quest for Earth before the Cylons gain enough strength to obliterate
> them once and for all.*

It stands to reason that as a minimum you'd want to have seen all the episodes that led up to the divergence point, especially those relating to the initial assault on the 12 colonies, the harassment of the fleet and the arrival of the Pegasus.